# Execution failed During Build APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, build

I want to build an APk in Android Studio. If I run the project normally(Run/Run App), there is no problem and I get BUILD-SUCCESSFUL(with some errors). But when I want to build APK through Run/Build APK, unfortunately I get BUILD-FAILED and the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/sun/activation/registries/LineTokenizer.class

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.exp.Artoosh'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 3
        versionName "0.4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/mimetypes.default'
        exclude 'META-INF/mailcap.default'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile  'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.6' 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Could you please help me and tell me a solution?

Comment: Add multidex in gradle!

Comment: As you can see above, I did it. But ....

Comment: Still same issue?

Comment: `compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'` and 
    `compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.6'` both have same class `LineTokenizer` under same package. Find which one you exactly want to use and remove another one!

Comment: @AndiGeeky: How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. 
The problem is that I used javax.mail and com.sun.mail together. First one is belongs java and second one belongs Android. I deleted javax.mail and added com.sun.mail instead, as you see in the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile  'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.6'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.6'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run this in terminal

```
./gradlew clean
```

or

run    **Build/Clean Project**